# summernote is there a way to setup "background-image" for an element?

Tags: background-image, summernote

I come around to setup an background-image for summernote wysiwyg editor, let me know is there any control I need to set or any wysiwyg editor supports this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Summernote does not explicitly support setting background images in the editor. You should, however, be able to do so by setting the background in css on the `.note-editable` class, just make sure to do so after Summernotes declaration, i.e. include your style after the Summernote stylesheet. Keep in mind using backgrounds could make the visual appearance of elements inside the editing area harder to visualise.